# Run PostgreSQL built-in functions in HeidiSQL

Tags: postgresql, hash, sha256, heidisql

I'm trying to run the `sha256` function in HeidiSQL, but I'm getting that function doesn't exist. The query is the following:

```
UPDATE db_name.users 
SET db_name.users.password = sha256(db_name.users.password)
WHERE user_id = (secret_numeric_id);
```

Is anything I'm doing wrong about the query or is HeidiSQL itself?

Here's the error message:

```
ERROR: function sha256(character varying) does not exist.
LINE 2: SET db_name.users.password = sha256(db_name.users.password)

HINT: No function matches in name and argument types. It may be necessary to add explicit type conversion.
```

**EDIT**

Running the following query:

```
UPDATE db_name.users 
SET db_name.users.password = sha256(convert_to(db_name.users.password), 'LATIN1')
WHERE user_id = (secret_numeric_id);
```

I'm getting the same error message, with different param type:

```
ERROR: function sha256(bytea) does not exist.
LINE 2: SET db_name.users.password = sha256(db_name.users.password)

HINT: No function matches in name and argument types. It may be necessary to add explicit type conversion.
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message you get (please **[edit]** your question, don't add additional information as comments)

Comment: I added the error message. I haven't add an image because it is in Spanish

Comment: Well, `sha256()` expects a `bytea` value, not a varchar. And it also returns a `bytea` so you wouldn't be able to assign the result to a `varchar` column. Btw: `db_name` in your SQL refers to a _schema_ not a "database".

Comment: You're right about the param type, thanks. But I'm getting the same error making a conversion. Also, `db_name` is the database. I have edited my question

Comment: `db_name` can't be the "database" as that would be invalid SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please, could you add your comment as an answer to mark as accepted? It have helped me a lot!